# Transparent view with visible subviews using IB

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a view which is created using IB. That view have some subviews like labels, buttons etc. What I want is to set view to be transparent but not it's subviews. 
I'm looking for some code free solution. Using IB only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IB, just select the parent view and click the "background" drop down list and select "clear color". Set the background for each subview to what you want in the same manner.